# Rails Bootstrap Modal fields do not get focused on clicking jquery-ui conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails app using Bootstrap.  I'm creating a modal to enter labor against a workorder.  The modal shows up fine.

But, if you left click on a field to enter data, it does nothing.  Yet, if you right click, you can enter data.  Plus the dropdown selector doesn't work.  Also the calendar selector shows up only if you right click. The `save` & `close` buttons, and the checkbox work fine.

Here is a pic from the browser:

[image]

The modal code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#eventform-<%= workorder.id %>">
  <i class="icon-time"></i>
  <%= render :partial => "eventform", locals: {workorder: workorder} %>
</a>
```

The `_eventform.html.erb:

```
<div id="eventform-<%= workorder.id %>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eventformLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&#215;</a>
  <h4 id="eventformLabel">Add Labor -
    Employee: <%= current_user.employee.employee_full_name %>
    - Workorder: <%= Workorder.find(workorder.id).wonum %>
  </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= simple_form_for Event.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :employee_id, :value => current_user.employee.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :workorder_id, :value => workorder.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :maxsynch, :value => "N" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :all_day, :value => true %>
    <div class="span3">
      <%= f.association :actcode, :label_method => :act_desc, :label => 'Activity', :include_blank => true %>
      <%= f.input :hours, :label => 'Hours' %>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <%= f.input :title, :label => 'Work Performed' %>
      <%= f.input :starts_at, :as => :string, :label => 'Date', :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker', :value => Date.today.to_s} %>
      <%= f.input :overtime, :label => 'Overtime' %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit 'Save', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %>
      <a class="btn btn-mini" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

If I remove `//= require jquery.ui.all` from application.js, then the fields work.  But, then I loose jquery.ui functionality.

UDPATE2

The problem goes away if I remove 'gem fullcalendar'